# php web service only returning one row from table

Tags: php, sql, web-services

I have a pretty simple php web service, but it is only returning one row.  I need to return all rows in the table.  I'm am iOS Developer trying to do some of the backend web services programming so I would consider myself a beginner in this subject.  Below is my code, is there something I am missing that makes it return all rows?

```
<?php
require_once "../database/config.php";
header("Content-type: application/json");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ft_client";
$res = mssql_query($sql);
if (mssql_num_rows($res)) {
    $op = mssql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $op['response'] = 200;
} else {
    http_response_code(420);
    $op = array('response' => 420);
}

echo json_encode($op);
mssql_close();
?>
```

I'm not a beginner in SQL and I know that the SELECT * should be grabbing everything from the table, I'm sure its a simple fix... a little help, please?

Comment: `mssql_fetch_assoc` will only return one row at a time. If you want all of them, use a loop and generate your return array.

Comment: Could you point me in a direction for creating a loop, or is there a simpler solution besides mssql_fetch_assoc that will return all rows at a time?

Comment: `while($op = mssql_fetch_assoc($res)) { $arr[] = $op } echo json_encode($arr);` is a quick example.

Comment: works like a charm! I added an answer, but feel free to add your comment as an answer.  I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres what I ended up with after some help from Jon Stirling.  While loop grabs all rows and adds to the array $arr, which I then echo the $arr and get my results.

```
<?php
require_once "../database/config.php";
header("Content-type: application/json");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ft_client";
$res = mssql_query($sql);
if (mssql_num_rows($res)) {
    while($op = mssql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
    { 
        $arr[] = $op; 
    } 
    echo json_encode($arr);
} else {
    http_response_code(420);
    $op = array('response' => 420);
    echo json_encode($op);
}
mssql_close();
?>
```